# Load csv file into SQL Server table

Tags: bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk copy from my `.csv` file into a SQL Server table, but it's not working.

CSV file content:

```
empid,first_name,last_name
1,Jeni,G
2,Niki,S
3,Broke,D
```

SQL Server table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
   [empid] [varchar](109) NOT NULL,
   [first_name] [varchar](109) NULL,
   [last_name] [varchar](19) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Format file:

```
11.0
133
1       SQLCHAR             0       0       "\""         1      empid                                                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\"\t\""     2        first_name                                                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\"\t\""     3     last_name                                                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Batch script:

```
 BULK INSERT [dbo].[emp] FROM 'C:\emp.csv' 
 WITH 
     (FORMATFILE='C:\emp.fmt');
```

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve bulk copy data from a `.CSV` file into a SQL Server table? Is there any other possibilities - if so, please let me know!

Thanks,

Comment: To begin with, I've never seen any 'bat script' with that syntax or layout.

Comment: Hi Compo, you are telling like below
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 BULK INSERT [dbo].[emp] FROM 'C:\emp.csv' 
 WITH 
     (FORMATFILE='C:\emp.fmt');

Comment: `WITH` is not a batch file command, and neither is `(FORMATFILE='C:\emp.fmt');`. So if you have an actual batch file, please post a [mcve] of it inside your question body, and format it so that it appears exactly within the code box as it should in the batch file's content.

Comment: Ok Compass, sorry for the inconvenience i am new to bat script, can you please share any example load csv file data into sql server table using bat script, sftpc command,
Example:

 bcp [dbo].[emp] in %empCsv% -F2 -f %FormatFile%  -T

Comment: Or let me know any BatFiddle example

Comment: Jennifer Rose, as I have absolutely no idea what 'BatFiddle' is, I am unable to provide you with an example. I also ask that you correctly address me, should you wish for me to provide future responses. This site is supposed to assist you to fix a single specific issue with your provided code in a single language, it is not here to provide a one to one tutor service. Please use the search box at the top of the page, and any other resources available to you to research how to perform your task, before writing your own code, and updating your question accordingly using the [edit] facility.